# Using the ADAL library to authenticate to Azure in the background without redirect to Azure login portal

Tags: azure, owin, adal

At the moment, I use the following code to prompt a redirect to the Azure login portal to enter a valid username and password at the Azure login screen:

```
public void SignIn()
{
    // Redirect to the Azure sign in page.

    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUrl }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    } 
}
```

How could i change the above code so that instead of redirecting to Azure first and entering a username and password over there, I can enter a username and password directly from my website and pass the credentials along in the background to Azure, get an authentication token back and finally redirect to the return url specified?

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported. The only place where a user should enter azure ad credentials is the azure ad credentials gathering page. Everything else is disallowed, including hosting that page in an iframe. That's for security reasons.
HTH
V.

Comment: Thanks vibronet, I decided to manage it manually on my website (added an answer for myself)

Answer (score 0):

Decided not to use the ClaimsPrincipal from the Azure AD and do the following instead and manage the session for current user manually on my website:

```
private static string GetUserID(string userName, string password)
{
    // Acquire the token for this user attempting to access the API.

    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
    var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(ApiResource, ClientId, new UserCredential(userName, password));

    return result.UserInfo.UniqueId;
}
```

Comment: Zen Pak, before following this approach, you should really examine if there is really not another option. From the [OAuth 2.0 RFC section on Resource Owner Password Credentials flow](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3): "The credentials should only be used when there is a high
   degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged application), **and when other authorization grant types are not available** (such as an authorization code)." (Emphasis added.)

Comment: I would say that it is ok to do this with things that the application itself is authorized to access and is not based on end user authentication.  For example, with Kayak, the application itself may be able to read flight schedules, whereas access to an individual's bookings would rely on user authentication.